# Bidirectional foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I'm thinking of designing a database schema similar to the following:

```
Person (
  PersonID int primary key,
  PrimaryAddressID int not null,
  ...
)

Address (
  AddressID int primary key,
  PersonID int not null,
  ...
)
```

Person.PrimaryAddressID and Address.PersonID would be foreign keys to the corresponding tables.

The obvious problem is that it's impossible to insert anything into either table. Is there any way to design a working schema that enforces every Person having a primary address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"I believe this is impossible. You cannot create an Address Record until you know the ID of the person and you cannot insert the person record until you know an AddressId for the PrimaryAddressId field."

On the face of it, that claim seems SO appealing.  However, it is quite propostrous.

This is a very common kind of problem that the SQL DBMS vendors have been trying to attack for perhaps decades already.

The key is that all constraint checking must be "deferred" until both inserts are done.  That can be achieved under different forms.  Database transactions may offer the possibility to do something like "SET deferred constraint checking ON", and you're done (were it not for the fact that in this particular example, you'd likely have to mess very hard with your design in order to be able to just DEFINE the two FK constraints, because one of them simply ISN'T a 'true' FK in the SQL sense !).

Trigger-based solutions as described here achieve essentially the same effect, but those are exposed to all the maintenance problems that exist with application-enforced integrity.

In their work, Chris Date & Hugh Darwen describe what is imo the true solution to the problem : multiple assignment.  That is, essentially, the possibility to compose several distinct update statements and have the DBMS act upon it as if that were one single statement.  Implementations of that concept do exist, but you won't find any that talks SQL.

Comment: this answer filled a gap in my knowledge about the Working of SQL.

Comment: I think there is a caveat... This answer may assume that the FK relationship in question is for a NOT NULL column.  However FK relationships applied to nullable columns is possible, and therefore a bidirectional foreign key constraint could be possible.

Comment: In his 1990 book, Codd advocated that in FK checking, the DBMS should effectively ***disregard*** all rows that have a NULL in the columns concerned.  So *no FK checking at all* if one column in the foreign key value is NULL, and if a potential match is with a referenced key that has a NULL column (hence cannot be a primary key), that referenced row too should be considered non-existing.  I don't know 100% if SQL's behaviour matches that pattern, but it does make the phrasing "applicable to nullable columns" rather suspect/dodgy/contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect example of many-to-many relationship. To resolve that you should have intermediate PERSON_ADDRESS table. In other words;

```
PERSON table
person_id (PK)

ADDRESS table
address_id (PK)

PERSON_ADDRESS
person_id (FK) <= PERSON
address_id (FK) <= ADDRESS
is_primary (BOOLEAN - Y/N)
```

This way you can assign multiple addresses to a PERSON and also reuse ADDRESS records in multiple PERSONs (for family members, employees of the same company etc.). Using is_primary field in PERSON_ADDRESS table, you can identify if that person_addrees combination is a primary address for a person.

Comment: I don't think this actually solves the problem - it just avoids it by relaxing the relationship. This similar to dropping the foreign key constraint on Address.PersonID

Comment: Then you should enforce this business rule (every person must have primary address) by a trigger on the PERSON table. The model I described should support that business rule.

Answer (score 2):

We mark the primary address in our address table and then have triggers that enforces only record per person can have it (but one record must have it). If you change the primary address, it will update the old primary address as well as the new one. If you delete a primary address and other addresses exist, it will promote one of them (basesd ona series of rules) to the primary address. If the address is inserted and is the first address inserted, it will mark that one automatically as the primary address.

Comment: This is definitely the design I've seen before - except without the triggers and enforcement being in the application. Aside from the extra maintenance, I'm not sure how reliable triggers would be. Are you sure that they cover all possible scenarios?

Comment: Yep, I'm sure and our triggers were very carefully tested and have worked without problem for years. Agree that using triggers to do this is a complex process (but so is doing it in the application and that is a far greater risk to data integrity) and they must be carefully tested (especially with multiple recordset inserts/updates/deletes). 

Triggers are critical to our system as we receive data from many applications and many other sources (we do several hundred data imports a week). This process must be in a trigger if you want to ensure data integrity.

Comment: A better approach instead of triggers would be a unique key constraint on a computed column "UniqueColumn as case when IsPrimary then PersonID else null end"

Answer (score 0):

The second FK (PersonId from Address to Person) is too restrictive, IMHO. Are you suggesting that one address can only have a single person?

Comment: Yeah, each address is specific to one person. I don't think it would make much difference though if I turned it into a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Will you *ever* share address records? Could Mr. Person and Mrs. Person share the same Address, or would they have separate (but identical) Address records?

Comment: No, Address records will never be shared.

Answer (score 0):

From your design, it seems that an address can apply to only one person, so just use the PersonID as the key to the address table, and drop the AddressID key field.

Comment: Each person can have multiple addresses.

Comment: Yes. That was my reasoning for putting a PrimaryAddressID column in the Person table rather than having a IsPrimary column in the Address table.

Comment: Then you will have to allow a null value in your PrimaryAddressID field and enforce the business rule in your application rather than in the db - OR you could allow the PersonID field in the address table to be null, then fill it in later - OR you could key the address table with PersonID and AddressNumber

Comment: Can you explain "you could key the address table with PersonID and AddressNumber"?

Comment: Add a new AddressNumber field to the table and the key - thkey becomes PersonID and AddressNumber, replacing the original AddressID key. The first address for a person then gets AddressNumber 1, the second gets AddressNumber 2, etc. The numbers do not have to be sequential, and there can be gaps when addresses are deleted. I don't usually like two-field primary keys, so I would probably not use this solution myself - I would either allow null in the PrimaryAddressID field so I could fill it in later, or use a many-to-many table as someone else suggested.

Answer (score -1):

I know I'll probably be crucified or whatever, but here goes...

I've done it like this for my "particular very own unique and non-standard" business need ( =( God I'm starting to sound like SQL DDL even when I speak).

Here's an exaxmple:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON(
    ID INT, 
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
    ADDRESS_ID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), 
    CONSTRAINT PERSON_UQ UNIQUE KEY (ADDRESS_ID, ...));

INSERT INTO PERSON(ID, DESCRIPTION) 
    VALUES (1, 'GOVERNMENT');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADDRESS(
    ID INT, 
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
    PERSON_ID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), 
    CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_UQ UNIQUE KEY (PERSON_ID, ...), 
    CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_PERSON_FK FOREIGN KEY (PERSON_ID) REFERENCES PERSON(ID));

INSERT INTO ADDRESS(ID, DESCRIPTION) 
    VALUES (1, 'ABANDONED HOUSE AT THIS ADDRESS');

ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD CONSTRAINT PERSON_ADDRESS_FK FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS(ID);
```

<...life goes on... whether you provide and address or not to the person and vice versa>

I defined one table, then the other table referencing the first and then altered the first to reflect the reference to the second (which didn't exist at the time of the first table's creation). It's not meant for a particular database; if I need it I just try it and if it works then I use it, if not then I try to avoid having that need in the design (I can't always control that, sometimes the design is handed to me as-is). if you have an address without a person then it belongs to the "government" person. If you have a "homeless person" then it gets the "abandoned house" address. I run a process to determine which houses have no users

Comment: The standard solution to this **is** to use deferred constraints (as Erwin mentioned). However not all DBMS are advanced enough to support that.