# Best Practise: Store members in same table as array or seperate table?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have a table of group information. Is it good to store *group members* in same group information table as *array* in a column? or should I create a separate table for group members?

I am using *mysql DB*, and *RDBMS* says to split data as much possible and so I am thinking to prefer the 2 tables option. Any suggestion?

Comment: Well, your question will be removed. This is not for which is best questions, but for specific issues.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thanx Randy. So you suggest me 2nd option.

Comment: Yes Chaibi Alaa. But it was a prior safety I wanted to take. As it might cause many issues in later phase. This decision is important

Comment: Yes, I would definitly split your data into different tables. For your future questions though, please use this site for programming issues (**bugs in code**). You can check out [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) for "getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development".

Comment: Sure Randy. Thanx a lot

Comment: Well, it depends on their relationship. in a many to many relationship, you should use a pivot table, in a one to many relationship, you can use a relation table, or you can use a seperate table with foreign keys on second table, in a many to one relationship, you can use a .. you got the idea. if it's a one to one relationship, you can use one table or split tables. it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Yeah Taha,
It will be many to many relation. One user(member) can be in many groups, and one group will have many members

Comment: In addition, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24451701/916000 says that "you don't normalize anything by putting data into a 1:1 related separate table".

Comment: Then you "need" to split the table. This is a requirement, not a best practice.

Comment: OK Taha. Thanks I will do that