# Should I use one-to-one relationships to avoid repetition even if the new table wasn't really needed?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a database from scratch and I'm wondering if the way I'm using one-to-one relationships is correct.

Imagine I have a table that needs the columns `city` and `country_id`, the first being alphanumeric and the second being a foreign key to another table.  Should I place these in a locations table and use a one-to-one relationship?

Another example:

I have a table with the factory information of a device like the serial number and other fields. These will later be used to register a device in another table. Of course this is a one-to-one relationship, but should the columns of the first table be in the second table instead? Have in mind that the `registrations` table has another 4-5 columns.

I've read a lot of times that these relationships can often be omitted. However, I like the separation of concerns that creating a new table can give, in some cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: update your question add  a proper  data sample and the expected  result  .

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate question, e.g. see:
[SQL one to one relationship vs. single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449642/sql-one-to-one-relationship-vs-single-table)

There's no perfect answer to this question as it depends on use case, but here's the rule of thumb I recommend abiding by: if you can *already* envision the *potential* need for separate tables, then I would err on the side of splitting them and using a 1:1 relationship. For example, imagine in the future that you want to have some kind of one-to-many relationship between some new table and the `country` table, or between some new table and the `device` table. In these cases you probably *don't* want city information mixed up with the former, and you probably *don't* want device registration information mixed up with the latter. By keeping your DB schema normalized, you can better future-proof it and you can mitigate the need for (likely extremely painful) updates that may have otherwise cropped up.