# Insert data into two table with Foreign key dependencies

Tags: mysql

How to insert data into two tables in same database which has foreign key dependencies on each other. Here i need to insert data into product table but it fails since it is referencing a column in sku table(which has no data). The second query inserts data to sku table where a `DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ID` column entry references a product table entry which also has no data. So How can i insert the data and make reference to each other column in both product and sku table?

**Error:**

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`sodifkj`.`sku`,  CONSTRAINT `FK28E82CF77E555D75` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ID`) REFERENCES `product` (`PRODUCT_ID`))

**Query:**

```
-- insert into product
INSERT INTO `product` 
(`PRODUCT_ID`, `ARCHIVED`, `DISPLAY_TEMPLATE`, `IS_FEATURED_PRODUCT`, `MANUFACTURE`, `MODEL`, `URL`, `URL_KEY`, `DEFAULT_CATEGORY_ID`, `DEFAULT_SKU_ID`, `SIGNATURE_TYPE_ID`, `CAN_SELL_WITHOUT_OPTIONS`, `TAX_CODE`) 
VALUES ('130', 'N', NULL, '\0', NULL, NULL, '/sig/Persl171', NULL, '4', '1030', 'FREE', NULL, NULL);
```

```
-- insert sku
INSERT INTO `sku` (`SKU_ID`, `ACTIVE_END_DATE`, `ACTIVE_START_DATE`, `AVAILABLE_FLAG`, `DESCRIPTION`, `CONTAINER_SHAPE`, `DEPTH`, `DIMENSION_UNIT_OF_MEASURE`, `GIRTH`, `HEIGHT`, `CONTAINER_SIZE`, `WIDTH`, `DISCOUNTABLE_FLAG`, `IS_MACHINE_SORTABLE`, `LONG_DESCRIPTION`, `NAME`, `RETAIL_PRICE`, `SALE_PRICE`, `TAXABLE_FLAG`, `WEIGHT`, `WEIGHT_UNIT_OF_MEASURE`, `FULFILLMENT_TYPE`, `INVENTORY_TYPE`, `TAX_CODE`, `CURRENCY_CODE`, `DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ID`) 
VALUES 
('1030', NULL, '2013-02-20 01:00:00', 'N', 'Person171', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '80', NULL, '65', 'N', '0', 'Person171', 'Person171', '0000', '0000', 'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '130');
```

I tried to run this query between a transaction and if success commit. But this din't work.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO product..
INSERT INTO sku..
COMMIT
```

Comment: Is Product_ID in Product table is auto increment or just int?

Comment: You can't have bidirectional foreign key constraints, because then there's no possible order of insertion that's valid.

Comment: You can disable foreign-key check and then do both inserts and reenable the check (which kind of defeats the purpose of having foreign keys).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bidirectional foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607916/bidirectional-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: @towr i disable the foreign key check and then inserted the data in both the tables..yes this defeats the foreign key purpose..just curious if there is a workaround or something..

Comment: @VigneshKumar it not an auto-incremental column value..

Comment: Needing two "owning" sides in a relationship suggests something's not right with the db design. Can a product have many skus, or a sku have many products, or both?

Comment: @namxal You could make one of the foreign keys nullable, and then assign that key at the end. That's the only alternative I've found so far for mysql/innoDb. (If you're prepared to switch databases, I think postgress allows deferred constraint checks.)