# MYSQL - Foreign key does not block invalid input

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

Im using easyPHP devserver-17, phpmyadmin 4.7.4, MySQL5.7.17

I have 2 tables, one that contains information about characters (hanzitable) and another that tells me how two characters are related to eachother. I don't want the second table to contain entries that don't correspond to an entry in the first.

I have a foreign key relationship set up that seems to work because I can't delete the line from the hanzitable that is referenced in the radicals table.

However, nothing is stoping me from adding rows to the radicals table that do not reference a value from the hanzitable table. If I use the insert function of phpmyadmin it **does** give me a dropdownbox with the values from the first table, but if I then edit the sql-query it generates to non-existing values the lines still get added.

Both tables use the InnoDB storage type.

I'm trying to do this from phpmyadmin so below are the relevant screenshots.

[Table 1 structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOK5r.png)

[Table 2 structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnEOi.png)

What am I missing here?

EDIT:
@Jeff
No, the radicals table should only accept entries that can be already be linked to two hanzitable entries. I'll fill the hanzitable first and then define the relationships between the hanzitable-entries in the radicals table.

@Philipxy
I'm not talking about bidirectional FK-constraints: hanzitable should and will have entries that do not come up in the radicals table.

Explicitely: 
I want all values in 'parent' column of the radicals table to represent values from 'ID' in hanzitable

AND

I want all values in 'child' column of the radicals table to represent values from 'ID' in hanzitable.

**There are two FK-constraints, but they're both in the same direction**.

*"If I then edit the sql-query it generates to non-existing values the lines still get added" is not clear"*

You're right, that was a little hazy. What I mean is:

```
INSERT INTO `radicals` (`Parent`, `Child`) VALUES ('100', '25')
```

Creates an entry in the radicals table, even when neither 100 or 25 exists in the hanzitable.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. The radicals table must be able to add entries in preparation for linkage to the hanzitable. If you don't want orphaned records in the radicals table then you might have to set up a query to periodically clean out the radicals table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bidirectional foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607916/bidirectional-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: "if I then edit the sql-query it generates to non-existing values the lines still get added" is not clear. This is a faq. Logically, there is a FK in both directions. (A case of an "equality dependency".) Which in typical SQL DBMSs you cannot enforce declaratively; you can use one table, or a FK & trigger, or deferred constraints. (Is it not unlikely that you are the first to have this problem?) [Please use text for text (including tables), not links & images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097)

Comment: Please see my edit